# How to fix divs alignment using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

How, using bootstrap, I can align all div elements on the red line?

**Incorrect:**
[image: Not at red line]

**Correct:**
[image: At red line]

Content in div may not be same and this is a problem. Divs where content is few paragraphs in the middle. Where a lot of text otherwise.

And I need to put all divs top edges on the all pages to a one position.

Comment: you want to change your Divs in Image 1 To Image 2 ? You have code that you want change or just you want structure code by bootstrap ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want , I write a code for you : http://jsfiddle.net/Tr4him/dSK3P/  @Aikoku

Comment: I didn't understand even one word of your question. Which style do you want? Right or Left??????

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the bg2 class to this. Yo have a margin top on it which is pushing the container to be larger and makes the gap. http://jsfiddle.net/dSK3P/2/

```
.bg2 { background-color: blue;margin-bottom: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this jQuery code could help you. I use this code to separate nav bar from content or vice versa.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('content').css('margin-top', parseInt($('#main-navbar').css("height"))+10);
});

$(window).load(function () {
    $('content').css('margin-top', parseInt($('#main-navbar').css("height"))+10);
});
```